# What is the REST way to update a record without primary key?

Tags: rest, api, post, patch, put

I've created a REST API. According to my design, we have to store user's blood sugar level per **daily basis**.

**The problem is:**

- I want to use single endpoint for the insert and the update operations
- I don't want to use primary key of the `blood-sugar` resource in the URI because i want to store only the **last value** for a **single day**.

---

For example if I make this call

```
POST https://{host}/users/1/blood-sugar/

{
    "measureDate": "2019-05-04",
    "bloodSugarLevel": 86
}
```

It will create a `blood-sugar` resource and the database will assign and ID (let's say `ID=333`)

It's OK until here.

Then, I want to be able to make a second request with same date but  different blood sugar level. As a result, i want to the backend should find the previous `blood-sugar` resource (with `ID=333`) and update the `bloodSugarLevel` field, because we already have a record for this day (`2019-05-04`). I don't want to send `ID=333` in the request body or URI.

```
POST https://{host}/users/1/blood-sugar/

{
    "measureDate": "2019-05-04",
    "bloodSugarLevel": 105 # only this value is different
}
```

**My question is:**

Is there any way to achieve this (or similar) result with REST? You can offer me to change the VERB or the URI or the request body.

> Note:
>   If I was doing this with WCF or similar thing, only single method would satisfy the all my requirements. For example: `CreateOrUpdateBloodSugarLevel(int userId, DateTime measureDate, int bloodSugarLevel)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve this (or similar) result with REST?

Just POSTing the updated value to the same endpoint is fine.

Think about how you would do this on the world wide web.  You would visit a website, and would load some form, containing a text field for date, a text field for bloodSugarLevel, and a submit button.  That would POST the message to the web server, and your browser would get back some response.

Note that, as a client, we really don't care whether the server appends the new message into a list, or upserts the message into a map, or does some clever thing with an RDBMS or a graph database.  Those are implementation details; part of the point of having a uniform interface is that the interface means that the clients (and generic components) don't really need to know what is happening.

Another application protocol that could work would be to treat bloodSugarLevel as a document that users can edit locally.  That way, a client could just use any HTTP aware editor to do the right thing.

```
GET /users/1/blood-sugar/

200 OK

{
    "measureDate": "2019-05-03",
    "bloodSugarLevel": 90
}

PUT /users/1/blood-sugar/
{
    "measureDate": "2019-05-04",
    "bloodSugarLevel": 86
}

204 No Content

PUT /users/1/blood-sugar/
{
    "measureDate": "2019-05-04",
    "bloodSugarLevel": 105
}
```

There are some semantic advantages to using PUT when the network is unreliable; because the server agrees that the message handing will be done idempotently, clients can respond to a timeout waiting for an acknowledgment by repeating the send.

Semantically, [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) means "upsert", but the underlying *implementation* doesn't have to be an upsert.  We're only making promises about the semantics that the client can expect.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. After i've read this, decided to use PUT for both scenarios.